# Local/Global isometries of the torus

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, symmetry

I am looking at isometries of the two-torus with the flat metric. From a local perspective, $T^2 = S^1 \times S^1$ has coordinates $(x,y)$, with metric:
$$ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2$$
The difference between $T^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ is in the topology, and comes from imposing the periodicity of the coordinates $x \sim x+1$ and  $y \sim y+1$.

I know that $\mathbb{R}^2$ has three Killing vectors: $\{ \partial_x,\partial_y, x\partial_y - y\partial_x \}$, which are simply the translations, and rotation of the plane. These are also local Killing vectors for the torus, but on the other hand I know that $T^2$ has only two global Killing vectors, the translations.

> How, explicitly, do I see that the rotation Killing vector is not a global Killing
>   vector for the two-torus?

Comment: Is the function $x$ well-defined on the torus?

Comment: No, it is only defined locally. So I should be able to compare the Killing vector at two points, $p = (x,y)$, and $p' = (x+1,y)$. In the manifold, $p = p'$, but the Killing vectors at these two points will be different, so the Killing vector is not globally defined on the manifold?

Comment: Think about it geometrically. Does rotation preserve the lattice?

Comment: @MarkB: Yep, that's the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments by [Jack Lee](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1421/jack-lee), the following is an easy way to see that the Killing vector is not globally defined:

On the manifold, the point $p=(x,y)$ is identified with the point $p'=(x+1,y)$. In order for the Killing vector $k=x\partial_y -y\partial_x$  to be globally defined, it should be the same at these two points. But we note that the Killing vector at $p'$ is given by $k(p')=x\partial_y -y\partial_x + \partial_y =k(p) + \partial_y  $. It follows then that $k$ is not a globally defined Killing vector.